# How to integrate a large blacklist with AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, filtering, blacklist, amazon-waf

I'm following [this example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-aws-waf-to-filter-incoming-traffic-from-embargoed-countries/) to filter incoming traffic from IP address ranges in a JSON file, using AWS WAF. The WAF file size-limit is 10,000 entries, and there is a max capacity of 500 WAF rules.

I would like to block a very large number of IP address ranges using AWS WAF - somewhere in the region of 500+ million. My initial thoughts are to store the entries in a database, and integrate the database with WAF. Is this possible, and if not, is there an alternative? There doesn't seem to be any recommended architecture for this in the AWS docs.

Comment: Have you considered cost of doing this? Just curious how much would it cost.

Comment: Don't know what you want to block, but AWS also has manged rules for common "problematic" IPs, such as from TOR, VPNs or known-bad IPs. Maybe some of their rules could help you reduce the number of IPs you want to block?

Comment: @Marcin No, I'm considering the technical feasability for now. Certainly cost analysis will come shortly after. The objective is to block a large series of IP addresses, which will rotate every 24 - 48 hours. The IP addresses are not well-known

Comment: You would probably get better answers if you could explain your purpose in blocking 1/8th of the IPV4 address space. But it's unlikely to involve WAF.

Answer (score 1):

AWS WAF can block specific CIDR range. Is all IP address in /32? If not, probably a lot easier to maintain this. Can probably use DynamoDB to maintain the list, then use lambda to fetch and update the IP set in WAF.